# $nearSphere query gives result java but how to calculate distance of each result?

Tags: java, javascript, mongodb

I am using $nearSphere query in mongoDB. I wanted the distance along with the list sorted by distance it gives.

I want to use this distance in javascript where I show results. I have used several formulas to calculate spherical distance between to points on earth. none gives me the exact distance which mongo used to sort?
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [$geoNear aggregation command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/geoNear/), you will also get the calculated distance back as well.

I found this in a [presentation given at MongoDB London](http://www.10gen.com/presentations/finding-pub-mongodb-24-geo-features) this year, it describes the use of $geoNear (slides 36 and 37), along with other geo features in MongoDB.

Alternatively, you can get an understanding of how some of the MongoDB geo features work in some of the following presentations:

- [Geo features webinar](http://www.10gen.com/presentations/webinar-mongodb-24-feature-demo-and-qa-geo-capabilities)
- [Geospatial Enhancements in MongoDB 2.4 video](http://www.10gen.com/presentations/geospatial-enhancements-mongodb-24)

I'm sure you've already found this via Google, but the MongoDB website has [documentation on Geospatial indexes/queries](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/)

Answer (score 0):

This was actualy very simple. To add in java create the query like below
e.g.

```
BasicDBObject distanceQuery = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject sphereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
sphereQuery.put("$nearSphere",new Double[]{lat, lan});
sphereQuery.put("$maxDistance", radiusInKm/6371);
distanceQuery.put("point", sphereQuery);
```

in the response you will get a "dist" param giving exact distance used to get the list.